# Verwendung von Vor- und Nachnamen vor Gästen (in Zusammenhang mit Du/Sie)

Tags: politeness

Gibt es übliche Formen, wie man geschickt mit dem Problem umgeht, wenn man im Team per-Du ist und mit einander vor und mit Gästen spricht, mit denen man natürlich per-Sie ist?

Gerade in einer größeren gemischten Gruppe kann es für Gäste ja schwer sein, dem Gespräch zu folgen und dann ins Gespräch einzusteigen wenn man sich konsequent Duzt. Ähnlich fühlt es sich eigenartig an, sobald ein Gast den Raum betritt zum Siezen überzugehen.

Beispiel:

- A.M.: „Sag mal, B., wer könnte denn wissen, wie man das macht?“ (zum Gast: „das ist Herr B.N.“)
- B.N.: „Da müsste man mal C. fragen“ (zum Gast: „das ist Frau C.O.“)
- Gast: „Was Herr N. sagt stimmt, aber bei Frau O. war ich schon.“

Das Problem ist hier in erster Linie die (für die Teilnahme des Gasts) nötige Zusatzinfo des Nachnamens, die nur durch die Extra-Erklärungen in Klammern geliefert werden.

Nebenprobleme könnten bei B.N. entstehen, der vor dem Gast vielleicht eher als „Herr N.“ als „der B.“ auftreten möchte.

Anders herum würde ein konsequentes Siezen dem Gast gegenüber nahelegen, dass in diesem Team trotz enger Zusammenarbeit Wert auf das „Sie“ gelegt wird…

Comment: Ich habe eine Weile gebraucht, um das Problem zu verstehen. Verstehe ich richtig, dass es nicht um den Unterschied zwischen Duzen und Siezen an sich geht, sondern um den Gebrauch von Vornamen oder Nachnamen?

Comment: Duzen und Siezen ist nicht identisch mit dem Gebrauch von Vor- oder Nachnamen. Die Überschrift leitet in die Irre und sollte korrigiert werden. Hier wird in allen Beispielen weder geduzt noch gesiezt. Es geht geht immer um Dritte, und da verwendet man die 3. Person, nicht die zweite.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn du und ich per-Du sind und ich über jemanden spreche mit dem ich per-Sie bin, dann spreche ich über denjenigen mit Herr oder Frau.
Beispiel: Ich: "Hallo Peter wie geht es dir?" Du: "Danke, gut." Ich: "Schau, Peter, da kommt Herr Müller."
Es ist nicht höflich und nicht üblich über Leute mit ihrem Vornamen zu sprechen, wenn man sie siezt.
Angenommen Herr Müller heißt Bernd mit Vornamen und ich hätte zu dir gesagt: "Schau, Peter, da kommt Bernd.",
dann hättest du angenommen, dass ich Herrn Müller auch duze und ihn ggf. ebenfalls geduzt. Das kann peinlich werden.

Comment: Wo gilt denn die Regel, dass man jemanden duzt, wenn der Gesprächspartner ihn duzt?

Comment: überall - außer ggf. in der Schule in der Lehrer die (jüngeren) SchülerInnen duzen und diese die Lehrer siezen. Wenn Du meinst, dass man eine dritte Person duzt, nur weil der Gesprächspartner sie duzt: natürlich nirgends außer ggf. in gewissen Freundeskreisen.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist etwas schwierig in Situationen bei der man manche Leute duzt und andere Leute siezt. Es gibt zwei Lösungsmöglichkeiten:

a) mit den mit Dir befreundeten Leuten absprechen bzw. darauf hinweisen, dass man jetzt hier *in diesem Kontext* diese auch siezt. Das kann in einer Diskussionsrunde auf einem Plenum oder so sinnvoll sein, wenn die Vornamen den Leuten nicht bekannt sind. Das klärt man dann mit seinen ebenfalls teilnehmenden Bekannten im Vorfeld und alles ist gut. Tut man das ohne es vorher abgesprochen zu haben, kann das leicht komisch bei Deinen Bekannten rüberkommen.

b) in einer etwas zwangloseren Atmosphäre, bspw. einem Empfang oder beruflichen Alltag redet man die Leute einfach so an wie die persönlich Ebene ist (duzen oder siezen). Und im Gespräch mit dritten Leuten verwendet man dann den Namen der Leute, die man duzt in Abhängigkeit davon, ob man davon ausgehen kann, dass der jeweilige Gesprächspartner auch den Vornamen kennt oder nicht:

b1) ich bin mit der genannten Person per Du, nennen wir sie in den Beispielen Gerda Markow: kennt der Gesprächspartner den vollen Namen der dritten Person (hier Gerda Markow), kann ich eine Formulierung mit Vornamen oder vollen Namen nutzen wie "... und Gerda (Markow) hat dann XY getan...". Besteht die Möglichkeit, dass der oder die Gesprächspartner nur den Nachnamen kennen, so ist die Nutzung des vollen Namens in jedem Fall unproblematisch. Natürlich ist es auch möglich dann im Gespräch auf "Frau Markow" hinzuweisen - allerdings empfinde ich das persönlich als etwas unangenehm, weil es eine Distanz zwischen ihr und mir schafft, die ja nicht da ist.

b2) Wenn man mit der dritten Person, der Gerda Markow, NICHT per Du bin, dann verwendet man in jedem Fall den Nachnamen, d.h. "Frau Markow". Da ist auch der Kontext des Gespräches mit anderen Personen egal, und auch ob Gerda Markow zugegen ist oder nicht.

Comment: Die einzige Situation, in der ich es bisher erlebt habe, dass Personen sich Siezen, obwohl sie eigentlich per Du sind, waren Parlamentsdebatten im Bundestag.